# Accessing symlink/softlink in shared folder from Virtual Machine

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox, symlink, shared-directory

I have a shared folder between my host machine and my VM that has been working smoothly, but I have run into problems when I tried to try to create a softlink to a folder on my host machine and share it. 
On my host machine, I have the folder /local_data which I can access from my virtual machine as /media/sf_local_data. In /local_data on my host machine, I created a softlink to a python project located in /home/user/PycharmProjects/targetFolder using the command:

```
ln -s /home/user/PycharmProjects/targetFolder/ /local_data/targetFolder
```

which is visible using ls -l in my VirtualBox:

```
lrwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf         40 Jun 18 11:49 SonarSetup -> /home/user/PycharmProjects/targetFolder/
```

but I can't copy or view anything inside.

I would like to be able to edit python code from my host machine and run it on my VM. I know, if nothing else works, I can move the whole folder over to /local_data but I would like to find out if I can get softlinks to work.